# If the arbitrary union of regular open sets in a topological space is a regular open set?

Tags: general-topology

I got to know that the finite intersection of regular open sets in a topological space is regular. But what about "union of regular open set"?
If this is regular I need the proof.
And if this is not true, then I need a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Take the intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. They are both regular open but the union is not since the closure is $[-1,1]$ whose interior is $(-1,1)\neq (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$.